# Pressing enter in textarea field refresh the page

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, textarea

I'm using Symfony2 but i'm experiencing a troubling thing.

I have a form, with a textarea field, but each time i press 'enter' to go to the next line it refresh the page (without deleting the previous line)..

Do you have any idea where does it come from?

Thanks!

Comment: The 1st think - you have some keypress (or keyup, keydown etc...) handlers on your textarea with form submit. Can you show us this page?

Comment: yess it was a JS script that the other developper sneaked in !
thanks for  your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for sure you have a submit button on the form. On enter in a form you call the submit butt that refreshes the page!

In order to prevent that you can just make the button in the type="button" and bind a onclick function so that the submit button is not called on enter!

However; you will remove the enter feature that calls the submit on the entire form not just in the text area!

OR --> you can just call a function on keypres or keyup on the text area and e.prevetnDefault();

I hope my answers helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer i just found out that the other developper sneaked into my code a js script... that was the problem!!

Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: submitting form is not default on "enter" for textarea.